# Error on CKEDITOR.replace() in Standard Package

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

When I try to call the replace-method of CkEditor with the standard package (plus German language pack), I get the following error in JavaScript:

> TypeError: d is undefined
>
> ...+f})}if(!a.blockless){var
>   d=a.lang.bidi;f("BidiLtr",d.ltr,"bidiltr",m("ltr"),10)...

If I use the full package (also with German language pack), everything works fine. Any ideas, what the problem might be? I just call the replace-method from the example in both cases:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
I had installed CKEditor 4.3.3.
After installing CKEditor 4.4.7 full the problems are fixed.